# Blender 2.79b weird shading glitch

Tags: rendering, shaders, blender-internal-render-engine

In blender 2.79b when I go into rendered view, or render it, the model has these weird shading glitches

[image: Only on two objects]

But it isn't apparent even on material view

[image: Material view]

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I fixed it by disabling auto smooth, I don't know what caused it though...

Comment: The model may have custom split normals, it happens with models exported from other softwares. Go to the mesh properties and remove the custom split normals

Comment: ahh, that makes sense, I do base modeling in 2.9 and port it to 2.7